# How to calculate CRC for ethernet frame correction?

Tags: swift, network-programming, crc, crc32

I need to implement error checking for an ethernet frame. How can I implement this?

I have gone through a few documents to understand how to check that an ethernet frame is valid. I tried to implement the algorithm described on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRC-32_algorithm) (in swift 5.1) :

```
    // we run the calculation over all the frame except the CRC itself (last 4 bytes)
    var crc : UInt32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    for x in 0..<(packetLength-4) {
        let byte = packetBytes[x]
        let nLookupIndex : UInt32 = (crc ^ byte) & 0xFF
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[Int(nLookupIndex)]
    }

    // This is the end padding (adding 4 bytes with 0 at the end)
    for x in 0..<4 {
        let byte : UInt32 = 0
        let nLookupIndex : UInt32 = (crc ^ byte) & 0xFF
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[Int(nLookupIndex)]
    }
```

where the crcTable looks like this:

```
let crcTable = [0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, .... 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d]
```

I can see that this is wrong, because it does not give me the crc that I see on ethernet frames. Is anyone able to point towards what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the table from? Is it for CRC-32?

Comment: I got the table from [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/System/IO/compression/Crc32Helper.cs,3b31978c7d7f7246,references) it is indeed for CRC-32.

Answer (score 0):

Include the data and CRC in the calculation. Since the CRC is post complemented, a recalculation of the CRC will be a non-zero constant, 0x2144DF1C.

Change the code to:

```
    var crc : UInt32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    for x in 0..<(packetLength) {           // fix
        let byte = packetBytes[x]
        let nLookupIndex : UInt32 = (crc ^ byte) & 0xFF
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[Int(nLookupIndex)]
    }
    if (crc != 0x2144DF1C){                 // if CRC != 0x2144DF1C
        // ...                              //   it is bad CRC
    }
```

Whenever a CRC is post complemented, a recalculation of CRC of data plus the CRC will result in a non-zero constant, in this case, 0x2144DF1C (if the CRC is not post complemented, the recalculated CRC will be zero).